# How to style the page if the data is not loaded in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

In angular application the divs, Images are created first after that properties are set so the problem is the broken images displayed for a while then the complete images are displayed. So what is technique to style the page if dynamic properties are not loaded.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Put the condition *ngIf="data != null" in your main div.

Comment: You should always check for your data with ngIf directive

Comment: for each div...?

Comment: To the parent div atleast...

Comment: You could also show some loading spinner as long as data is not there - it depends on your design.

Answer (score 1):

Use Resolve technique by angular, it is mainly used to load data per component before the component is loaded.
I've used, it's great, clean, and elegant!

here are a couple of references:

- https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/
- https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/

Good Luck!